# How to set/change host name using Chef?

Tags: ubuntu, chef-infra, knife

I have few nodes in running mode, I have to set hostname to those nodes.

Is there any Cookbook, in that we can set attribute host_name and run that recipe on respective nodes?

Comment: Hi I am looking for the same. can you help me out how use that recipe?

Comment: There is a community [hostname](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/hostname) cookbook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Author's note

This answer is over 6 years old.

As @lamont points out chef [now supports a hostname](https://docs.chef.io/resource_hostname.html) resources

---

## Original answer

There is a community [hostname](http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/hostname) cookbook.

Comment: How to use this recipe for centos ?

Comment: what are the changes that are required we require to make.

Comment: @user3086014 The documentation does not list centos as a supported OS. However the test kitchen file does test this cookbook using CentOS-6.4 and the default recipe contains centos logic. Have you tried this cookbook?

Comment: I haven't tried this cookbook!! I was not able to upload it successfully. I was not able to understand how to use it.

Comment: @user3086014 Post a new question with your error message. An inability to load the cookbook seems to be a more basic problem.

Comment: [chef-client now has a built-in hostname resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_hostname.html)

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: there is now a [hostname resource in the chef-client itself](https://docs.chef.io/resource_hostname.html) that was based on the chef_hostname cookbook in this answer, which is what everyone should use

I just released an initial version of a chef_hostname cookbook:

https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef_hostname

To use it declare that you depend on it in your metadata.rb:

```
depends "chef_hostname"
```

And then in you recipe code just use the `hostname` resource that it provides to set the hostname:

```
hostname "foo.example.com"
```

Or set the hostname to the node.name:

```
hostname node.name
```

Or set to any attribute that you care you use:

```
hostname node["set_fqdn"]
```

This cookbook solves many outstanding issues.  Including all the Issues and PRs that are open against the hostname cookbook:

- supports fedora correctly
- supports centos7 and systemd systems that use hostnamectl
- does correct idempotent line-editing of files like /etc/hosts and /etc/sysctl.conf
- node['fqdn'] works correctly after the hostname is set
- is considerably more portable already, and I'll be adding more operating systems later
- defaults to node['ipaddress'] for /etc/hosts, allows tweaking
- allows for disabling /etc/hosts editing completely

Answer (score 1):

Checkout my updated fork of the hostname cookbook that fixes a bug in hostname where the domain name gets appended twice to the FQDN.

Also, this fork allows you to set the ip to node["ipaddress"] instead of the default 127.0.1.1 or some other static ip.

https://github.com/nathantsoi/chef-cookbook-hostname

or

https://supermarket.getchef.com/cookbooks/hostnames

Comment: Thanks for the fork/fix.